# When is Spring in the USA?

Tags: usa, seasonal

I am from Australia and want to visit the United States of America in the spring season. I am unsure of when the American Spring is.

Comment: Weatherwise? Ticketwise? Or astronomywise?

Comment: Where in the USA? The answer is massively, massively different between, say, Alaska, Hawaii, California, Colorado, Florida, Maine, ...

Comment: Yeah, the question not well-formed.  The US is a huge country, stretching from 18°N (considerably south of Hong Kong) to 71°N (considerably north of Sweden).

Comment: @Malvolio But Sweden is a vast country too and certainly [stretches all the way to 70°N](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treriksr%C3%B6set)…

Comment: @Annoyed : Sweden is wonderful country -- the lovely lakes, the wonderful telephone system, and many interesting furry animals, including the majestic moose -- but its north-south extent fits entirely within a single US state.  If it were a US state, it would be tied for 11th place (with New Jersey) in population.  And its northernmost point is 100 km south of the US's Point Barrow.

Comment: @Malvolio I couldn't care less about Sweden, lakes or the moose, my point was merely that it's larger than it appears on most maps (indeed it's larger than all but two US states – why even bring up population?) or than most European countries (ahead of Germany, Italy or the UK…). Most importantly, 100 km does not sound “considerably” further north to me. Compared to the size of the US, it's a rounding error. That difference is in any case considerably less considerable than the north-south difference between Ka Lae and Hong Kong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The astronomical spring (Northern Hemisphere) 2014 begins on  **March 20** and ends on  **June 20**, that includes USA.

Comment: [Source](https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+in+usa&oq=spring+in+usa&gs_l=serp.3..0l7.2552.2704.0.2821.3.3.0.0.0.0.88.129.2.2.0....0...1c.1.42.serp..1.2.126.GXRDJS0zIMo).

Comment: I always thought it's the 21st.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Season#Mid-latitude_astronomical - Interesting, I thought astronomical seasons always begin on the 21st. So I was wrong.

Comment: @MeNoTalk You should include the link to the source in your answer. Comments are second class citizens on the SE network, which means that you shouldn't write important stuff *only* in comments.

Comment: @nyuszika7h: It starts and ends on the equinoxes and solstices. What dates those fall on vary by year and time zone, because a calendar year is not exactly a solar year (some are shorter, and some are longer (leap years)).

Answer (score 12):

It depends. If you're talking astronomical, as MeNoTalk says, it's from the equinox (mid-March) to the solstice (mid-June).  However, the temperatures don't necessarily reflect that.  You can still experience cold snaps and snow in the north right through much of April as well, while to many, the south (Texas, Florida) will be nice and warm already.

It's best to look up the Wikipedia article for the climate of the region you wish to visit. For example, in the city I'm currently in, [Melbourne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melbourne#Climate).

Comment: (+1) I think some parts of the US don't even have a spring at all but rather a climate closer to the two seasons that exist under the tropics.

Comment: @Annoyed It varies from year to year.

Comment: Another useful resource is WeatherSpark, which collates historical data and projects averages - [here is the dashboard for Melbourne](http://weatherspark.com/#!dashboard;q=melbourne)